# How to Set Banner in homepage above the 2-column with left bar?

Tags: magento-1.7, layout, design, cms-pages, custom-theme

I need to place banner in magento homepage. 
My homepage config:

> 1. I set my homepage as 2-column with leftbar in CMS -> Pages.
> 2. I need to set the banner in above 2-column with leftbar layout.

like this,
(HEADER)

(BANNER)

(2-COL with left bar).

Please help me I am new to magento.

Comment: Karthik,can you put layout.xml of that banner extension... also config.xml

Answer (score 1):

The best solution would be you create a new reference in app/design/frontend/YOURTHEME/default/template/page/2columns-left.phtml

Check this [link](http://universalcoder.wordpress.com/2014/03/29/how-to-add-a-new-reference-position-in-magento/) to know how to do it.

After creating the reference you can call the file of your desire using XML in CMS page custom design tab as described in the blog.

Comment: How to add CMS > Widget on  2columns-left.phtml @Dexter

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate a banner module for this and based on your requirement, you can call a static block for Banner like `{{block type="banners/banners" name="banners" template="banners/banners.phtml"}}` on homepage after the header part.

Answer (score 0):

As Dexter said, you need to add a new block reference. After that you can add your block using XML, or you can add one via CMS > Widget.